# If "X is a dependency of Y" then "Y is a ??? of X"

Tags: terminology

"X is a dependency of Y" means that Y depends on X (i.e. we have to import Y in X's  source code).

Is there a word that fits in "Y is a ??? of X", meaning X uses Y?

Comment: "Y is a dependent WHATEVER of X"?

Comment: Often times I find "consumer" to be appropriate, but it's also contextual.

Comment: X implements Y maybe

Comment: It depends on the context. Are you talking about mathematics, abstract logic, computer programming, economics, personal relationships, finance or something else?

Comment: @BoldBen, I was talking about computer programming, and asked this question in "software engineering", but for some reason it was moved to english language & usage.

Comment: @user56834 Sorry I didn't read the background properly, 
I assume that the situation is similar to having Y in a C source library which has to be #included before code containing X is compiled. However, looking at the question again, when you say <<means that Y depends on X >> shouldn't that be the other way around? Perhaps the word you are looking for is "prerequisite".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Dependent" is the general term but it's uncommon to say things like "X is a dependent of Y".  Usually you would say "X is dependent on Y", or "X has a dependency on Y" or as you write the question "X depends on Y".  The only time I can think of where I might use the term 'dependent' in this context is if I wanted to provide a list of things that depend on something I might label it: 'dependents'.

Answer (score 1):

"User" would be fine in the case of classes or libraries. "Client" in the case of services and APIs. The generic term is "dependee", but that sounds stilted and I wouldn't use it.

Comment: The dependent party would be the 'depender' not the 'dependee'.